# What is the angular velocity in the center of a rotating disc?

Tags: rotational-kinematics

The center of the disc is its center of mass and the motion of the disc is purely rotational (no translation).

Comment: I think you tried to ask about the center point on the rotating disc.

Comment: Just rotating or rolling ?

Comment: The **angular** (or rotational) velocity is not zero. But, while it does spin, the centre doesn't *move* anywhere. No translation. So, zero translational velocity.

Comment: BTW, it's considered bad etiquette on Stack Exchange sites to make changes to the question which invalidate existing valid answers.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Okay. Then the comment section is allowed to clarify the question? Or can I also change the body of the question?

Comment: Ideally, we use the comments to clarify the question *before* it starts receiving answers. In this case, the posted answers are all fairly short & basic, and I *suspect* the authors won't mind updating their answers. But it may take them some time to notice, depending on their time zones.

Comment: @SethGreenberg I have revised  my answer based on your revised title.

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass is a point. A point has no dimensions. Some definitions of angular velocity are

1. "angular velocity refers to how fast an object rotates or revolves relative to another point" (Wikipedia)
2. "The rate of rotation around an axis usually expressed in radians or revolutions per second or per minute" (Merriam Webster)

Given the above, ask yourself

1. Relative to what other point is the center of mass rotating?
2. About what axis is the center of mass rotating? Can a point rotate about itself?

Hope this helps.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the alert.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity of centre of the disc will be zero as the motion is purely rotational as seen from an inertial frame at rest.

Comment: Note that the OP has edited the title of the question to ask about *angular* velocity.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity of the centre of disc will be zero as the centre of the disc has same coordinates as the centre of mass and also, it has only pure rotational motion.

This is so because if the sum of the external forces is zero, the acceleration of the center of mass will be zero, and the velocity $v_{CM}$  of the center of mass will be constant. Usually we choose a reference system where  $v_{CM}$ is zero. The center of mass will then be at rest. Consequently, if the center of mass is at rest, there is no torque acting on it at that point and so, the total momentum is zero.
hence, we can say that $$v_{CM}=0$$

**EDIT:** Angular velocity,

$omega=v/r$

When the point is at the center, r=0.

Therefore, v/0 => undefined

Hence, the angular velocity of the center of the disc is undefined *if* the axis on which it rotates passes through the center of the disc.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the alert.